# aplicar eventRender en fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

buenas, estoy comenzando a utilizar fullcalendar en mi proyecto por lo que no se lo suficiente aun. mi problema es el siguiente: estoy trayendo varios datos en formato JSON a mi fullcalendar, pero solo a uno de ellos, necesito que se aplique la propiedad editable: true, y ademas la propiedad eventRender,sin embargo esta se aplica a todos los datos que traigo al fullcalendar, ahi alguna manera de realizar lo que necesito?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
           left: 'title',
           center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
           right: 'prev,next today'
        },
        editable: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        selectable: true,
        defaultView: 'month',
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_alerta',
            },
            {
                url: '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_ventas', 
            },
            {
                url: '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_compras',
            }
          ],
          eventRender: function(event, element, view){
            if (event.customRender == true)
            {
              var el = element.html();
              element.html("<div style='width:90%;float:left;'>" + el + "</div><div style='text-align:right;' class='cerrar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></div>");
                
              element.find('.cerrar').click(function(){
                  if(!confirm("Desea eliminar el evento?")){
                      return false;
                  }else{
                      var id = event.id;
                      $.post('<?= base_url() ?>calendar/delete_alerta',
                      {
                          id:id
                      },
                      function(data){
                          if(data == 1)
                              alert('se elimino el evento');
                          else
                              alert('error al eliminar');
                      });
                    $("#fullcalendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                  }         
              });
            }           
          }   
        });   
    });
    </script>
```

en este caso solo deseo que sea editable y ademas se aplique la propiedad eventRender, solo a los datos de url: 'calendar/get_alerta'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cómo hacer que sólo los eventos de una fuente sean editables**

Cuando haces el `eventSources` y especificas las URLs desde las que se van a leer los datos, puedes especificar también algunas propiedades que se aplicarán sólo a los eventos de esa fuente. Para este caso particular, lo que te interesa es la opción `editable` (puedes ver la [lista completa de opciones en la documentación oficial de FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/#options), en inglés).

Por lo que una solución rápida sería poner `editable` a `false` para el calendario, y para la fuente en concreto que quieras (`get_alerta`) especificar un valor de `true`. Algo como esto:

```
    ...
    editable: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    selectable: true,
    defaultView: 'month',
    eventSources: [
        {
            url: '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_alerta',
            editable: true
        },
        {
            url: '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_ventas'
        },
        {
            url: '<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_compras'
        }
    ],
    ...
```

---

**Cómo hacer que el `eventReader` se aplique sólo a los eventos de una fuente/url**

`eventReader` se va a llamar para todos los eventos. Lo que te interesa es poner un condicional para que sólo se aplique a los eventos que tú quieras y no a todos.

> Parece que ya tienes algo en tu código para esto. Me refiero al `if (event.customRender == true)` del principio del método. Si no me equivoco `customRender` no es una propiedad nativa de FullCalendar ([puedes ver las propiedades en este enlace](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)), eso quiere decir que cuando se generen los eventos sólo los que tengan `customRender:true` acabarán ejecutando la función.
>
> Entonces tendrías que asegurarte que los eventos de `get_alert` la tienen; mientras que los eventos de otras fuentes, no. Ejemplo de cómo serían los eventos del `get_alert`:
>
> ```
> [
>   {
>     "id": "1",
>     "title": "Evento 1",
>     "start": "2017-02-13 09:00:00",
>     "end": "2017-02-13 10:30:00",
>     "customRender": true
>   },
>   {
>     "id": "2",
>     "title": "Evento 2",
>     "start": "2017-02-14 10:00:00",
>     "end": "2017-02-14 11:30:00",
>     "customRender": true
>   }
> ]
> ```

Pero si no puedes/quieres modificar la fuente, o si la propiedad `customRender` también pudiera estar presente en alguna de las otras fuentes cuyos eventos no quieres que pasen por `eventRender`, hay otra opción:

Dentro de `eventRender` puedes comprobar de qué fuente viene el evento comprobando su propiedad `source` y la `url` (`event.source.url`). Entonces podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
    ....
    eventRender: function(event, element, view){
        if (event.source.url == "<?= base_url() ?>calendar/get_alerta") {
            ....
        }
    }
    ....
```

Que hará que el cuerpo de la función sólo se ejecute para los eventos que vengan desde `get_alerta`.

Comment: Muchas gracias.. Súper claro y lo que necesitaba.